# How to catch all the "warn" calls in your sub-routine in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, validation, xml-parsing, sax

I am using a Twig Parser to perform several account validation checks - and would like to grab all the 'warn' calls as they occur inside my 'process_account' subroutine (in order to display number of warnings each account has shown/etc).

Following is a chunk of my code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig; 
use Time::Piece; 

use vars qw/$user/; #User Choice (grabbed via another sub routine)

    sub process_account {
        my ( $twig, $account ) = @_;
        print "Account Name: ", $account -> first_child_text('Id'), "\tAccount Status: ", ($account -> first_child_text('Locked') eq 'false' ? "Not Locked" : "LOCKED"), "\n";
        my $logindate = join ( "-", map { $account -> first_child('LastLoginDate')->att($_) // 0 } qw ( year month day-of-month) );
        my $createdate = join ( "-", map { $account -> first_child('CreationDate')->att($_) // 0 } qw ( year month day-of-month) );

        if ($user == 1){
            #Checking if the LoginID length is between 7-15 & it only contains alphanumeric characters (the length limit will be changed as per the necessity)
            if ( $account -> first_child_text('Id') !~ /^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/ || 7 > length $account -> first_child_text('Id') || 14 < length $account -> first_child_text('Id') ) { 
                warn "\tALERT: Login Name is out of the defined Parameters.\n", return;
            }
        }
        if ($user == 2){
            # Checking if the LastLoginDate is older than the creation date.
            if ( eval{ Time::Piece -> strptime ( $createdate, "%Y-%m-%d" )} > eval{Time::Piece -> strptime ( $logindate, "%Y-%m-%d" )} ) {
                warn "\tALERT: Last Login Date is older than the creation date.\n", return; 
            }
        }
        if ($user == 3){
            #Checking if the Login Count has been incremented since the creation of this account.
            if (    $logindate eq 0 && $account -> first_child_text('LoginsCount') eq '0') {
                warn "\tALERT: Login Date exists but the Login Count is still '0'.\n", return; 
                }
            }
  $twig -> purge; #For Emptying the processed data (so far).
    }
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'Account' => \& process_account } );
$twig -> parsefile ($file);
```

I've tried several options (for eg using **Warn**)

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    state %WARNS;
    my $message = shift;
    return if $WARNS{$message}++;
    logger('warning', $message);
};
if ( (%WARNS) > 0 ) { #things i would like to do
   }
```

But none of the option is working and I would really appreciate your guidance in this regard.

Comment: And its Perl or perl but not PERL.

Comment: @serenesat (corrected) - do you have an answer to the question though ? (since its not the same as the previous one).
previous question: "how to parse the given file with Perl".
this question: "unable to retrieve the values from the inner hash".
and the received answers were not for SAX either !

Comment: I have re-opened this because it's different now, but what are you actually wanting as your result? Bear in mind that what you've got looks like it'll only trigger once for each warning type (which may occur multiple times in multiple accounts).

Comment: @Sobrique I want two things - Firstly the name of the account will only get printed if the account has any warning. Secondly if the account has any warning, print the number of warnings in that iteration as well.
I have edited my code chunk to include the part where the twig constructor is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I'd do this via `warn` and instead just keep a log of error events.

E.g.

```
my %warnings; 

sub log_warning { 
    my ( $account_id, $warning ) = @_;
    warn "$account id has problem with $warning\n";
    push ( @{$warnings{$warnings}}, $account_id );  
}
```

This will populate a warning hash, and you'll get a list of messages and which account ids triggered it.

You might invoke it with:

```
log_warning ( $account -> first_child_text('Id'), 
            "Login Date exists but the Login Count is still 0");
```

After your parsing is done, you'd be able to extract via:

```
foreach my $message ( keys %warnings ) { 
    print scalar @{ $warnings{$message}} . " warnings found of ". $message,"\n";
    print "Accounts:\n"; 
    print join ("\n\t", @{$warnings{$message}} ), "\n";
}
```

Something like that anyway.

If you're just after failed accounts - add:

```
my %failed_accounts;
```

And in that sub, - either just a count:

```
$failed_accounts{$account_id}++;
```

Or if you want a list of failures:

```
push ( @{$failed_accounts{$account_id}}, $message );
```

Which you can then report with:

```
foreach my $acc_id ( keys %failed_accounts ) { 
   print $acc_id, " has ", scalar @{$failed_accounts{$acc_id}}, " errors\n";
   print join ( "\n\t", @{$failed_accounts{$acc_id}}),"\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response - however, if I would like to print the name of the account id ONLY if it has any 'warn' messages - how I'll be able to do that (I'll appreciate if you'll take my code and insert the blocks of your response in their respective places and provide a complete set).

Comment: Still unable to comprehend :-(
If you can plot your solution in the code which I have given in my question and provide a working answer (which I can take and test) - that would probably do the job.
(Excuse my low understanding of Perl - I am fairly new to it).